# How to install correctly another Linux flavour (in my case PCLinuxOS) together with installed Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, partitioning, testing

Hello everybody and Prosperous and Productive Year 2011 !!!

I have Ubuntu 10.10 (32bit) installed on my laptop. I would like to install PCLinuxOS (KDE or LXDE version, I don't know yet) on the same computer across with Ubuntu 10.10. I would like to test 'in real conditions' a new PCLinuxOS as well as to resolve my question regarding Audio CD playback issue (mounting DBus timeout error).
I would be grateful if somebody can advise me how to perform the installation of another Linux flavour without breakdown :) of existing Ubuntu system ?

Thank you in advance for advices and recommendations.

Here is my current partitioning:
[image: 500Gb HDD]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resize your /home partition to a lower size so it gives a small space for PCLinux. With the extra space insert the PCLinuxOS Live CD. Just install it like Ubuntu BUT when selecting the place you want to install, install the root in the partition space you just made. You can have the /home pointing to the same one of ubuntu at /home.

So for example it might be like this

/dev/sda1        /       13.97GB
/dev/sda2                451.79GB (It holds inside all the logicals. NO Resize this one)
    /dev/sda5    /home       349.00GB (You made a 100GB Partition for PCLinux. 100GB Less Here)
    /dev/sda6           2.79GB   (The same SWAP. Except if you want to hibernate)
    /dev/sda7          100.00GB (Your new Partition for PCLinuxOS)

If you want to hibernate and all that create yet another swap so not to have the hibernated information in swap when you login with the other Distro.

After that when you finish installing PCLinuxOS you should see in the Grub both Distros.

Just wanted to add, With this question in my head: [What is GRUB (2)'s role in the suspend/hibernate process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17079/what-is-grubs-2-role-in-the-suspend-hibernate-process) there is now no need for 2 swaps. Grub will resume or tell you which Distro has been hibernated, so to not make a huge problem when booting. So it is almost safe to assume that you can have both /home shared and swap shared also. But need to take into consideration if you hibernated, WHICH one hibernated.

Comment: Cyrex, thank you very much for comprehensive answer and recommendations !

Comment: Just getting the ubuntu feeling right here friend. Enjoy.